# File reference in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, filepath

I would like to load a model in contentScript.js using url `'./model/model.json'`

```
const MODEL_URL = './model/model.json';
const model = tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_URL);
```

but keep getting `Request to model/model.json failed with status code 404. Please verify this URL points to the model JSON of the model to load.` Could not figure out what went wrong. I also tried `'../model/model.json'`, `'model/model.json'`, `'./model/model'` et. al..

```
├── build
│   ├── icons
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── model
│   │   ├──model.json
│   ├── contentScript.js
```

**Update**:

Added   `"web_accessible_resources": [ "models/*" ]` to `manifest.json`, still get 404.

Comment: If you load it in a content script, you need to use `web_accessible_resources`.

Answer (score 0):

use getURL():

```
tf.loadLayersModel(chrome.runtime.getURL(MODEL_URL));
```